# Select columns with values using null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to select column with not null values but it's not working..please tell me where is the problem. thank you

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT opt_one, opt_two, opt_three, opt_four, opt_five, opt_six FROM `table`
        WHERE `opt_one` IS NOT NULL AND `opt_two` IS NOT NULL AND `opt_three` IS NOT NULL AND
        `opt_four` IS NOT NULL AND `opt_five` IS NOT NULL AND `opt_six` IS NOT NULL AND  q_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error);
while($r3 = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $print = array($r3['opt_one'], $r3['opt_two'], 
   $r3['opt_three'],          
   $r3['opt_four'], $r3['opt_five'], $r3['opt_six']);
   shuffle($print);

   echo $print['0'];
   echo '<br>';
   echo $print['1'];
   echo '<br>';
   echo $print['2'];
   echo '<br>';
   echo $print['3'];
   echo '<br>';
   echo $print['4'];
   echo '<br>';
   echo $print['5'];
   echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Did you get error?

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: What means `but it's not working`?

Comment: i dont get error..i want to print only those have values but it print even columns with null values..i was expecting to print option 1 to 4 because 5 & 6 dont have values

Comment: yes its not working.

Comment: in condition try OR instead of  AND....then you get values...

Comment: OR is not working to

Comment: Stop. See normalisation. Normalise. Go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have empty as a value in your column not *NULL*. Try this:

```
SELECT opt_one, opt_two, opt_three, opt_four, opt_five, opt_six 
FROM `table`
WHERE (`opt_one` IS NOT NULL OR `opt_one` != '') 
AND (`opt_two` IS NOT NULL OR `opt_two` != '') 
AND (`opt_three` IS NOT NULL OR `opt_three` != '')
AND (`opt_four` IS NOT NULL OR `opt_four` != '') 
AND (`opt_five` IS NOT NULL OR `opt_five` != '')
AND (`opt_six` IS NOT NULL OR `opt_six` != '')
AND  q_id = '$id'
```

**Side Note:**

Stop using mysql_* extension its deprecated and closed in PHP 7, use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: thank you..im going to try this..maybe i should try to learn mysqli :-)

Comment: @Frank: for your learning, answer updated, explore shared links

Comment: it also wont work..maybe try to use mysqli..thank you

Comment: @Frank: try this two queries in php myadmin: `SELECT opt_one, opt_two, opt_three, opt_four, opt_five, opt_six 
FROM `table` WHERE opt_one != ''`
AND
`SELECT opt_one, opt_two, opt_three, opt_four, opt_five, opt_six 
FROM `table` WHERE opt_one IS NOT NULL`

Comment: The problem is one of poor design. This solution does nothing to address that - but it does have some useful advice right at the end.

Comment: @Strawberry: agreed with u